# Save the array numeric values in reverse in another array, then store the result in a variable as a numeric value

Tags: javascript, arrays

In general, in the following code, my goal was to store the values of the array from end to begining in a new array, then display it as a number,
Of course, in the meantime, I doubled the value of each array cell.

I want to know is there an easier way?

```js
let firstArray = [1, 2, 3];
const secondArray = [];
firstArrayLength = firstArray.length;

let i = 0;
let y = 0;

while (i < firstArrayLength) {
  secondArray.push(firstArray.pop());
  i++;
};

secondArrayLength = firstArrayLength;

while (y < secondArrayLength) {
  if (y == 0) {
    secondArray[y] = secondArray[y] * 100;
    secondArray[y] = secondArray[y] * 2;
  }
  if (y == 1) {
    secondArray[y] = secondArray[y] * 10;
    secondArray[y] = secondArray[y] * 2;
  }
  if (y == 2) {
    secondArray[y] = secondArray[y] * 1;
    secondArray[y] = secondArray[y] * 2;
  }
  y++;
}

let sum = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < secondArray.length; i++) {
  sum = sum + secondArray[i];
}

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Code review has its own site -> https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You're not doing anything with `secondArray` other than sum its elements. There's no need for that. You can get `sum` also with just the elements in `firstArray`.

Comment: I took the liberty to replace the code block with a snippet. The additional markup was not relevant for the topic of your question, hence I removed it (and replaced the only interaction with it with a `console.log(sum)`)

Answer (score 1):

A solution using one array, `Array.reverse()` and `map()` (By mutating the original array):

```js
let firstArray = [1, 2, 3];

firstArray.reverse(); // --> [3, 2, 1]

let sum = '';

firstArray.map(i => {
  sum += i*2+''
});

console.log(sum); // --> 642

// if you need integer value of sum
let int_sum = parseInt(sum)
```

A solution without mutating the original array:

```js
    let firstArray = [1, 2, 3];
    let sum = '';
    
    firstArray.slice().reverse().map(i => {
      sum += i*2+''
    });

    console.log(firstArray); // --> [1, 2, 3]
    console.log(sum); // --> 642
    
    // if you need integer value of sum
    let int_sum = parseInt(sum)
```

Comment: Why is `sum` a string (to be then parsed and stored as an integer in `int_sum`)? o.O

Comment: that was perfect -pukshan